# Do Record types' == operator perform equivalent comparisons to the 'Equals' method in classes implementing IEquatable<T>?

Tags: c#, class, record, iequatable

I have a class named 'Clock' that implements the IEquatable interface. I've implemented the 'Equals' method in my class to compare two objects like this:

```
public bool Equals(Clock? other)
{
    return _hours == other?._hours && _minutes == other._minutes;
}
```

When I changed my `class` to a `record` type and replaced the `Equals` method with the `==` operator, the results remained the same. Can I conclude that the Equals method in my class essentially performs the same comparison as the `==` operator does for record types?

Scenario one:
I have two objects of Clock class like this and want to check value equality of two objects using `Equals` method which I added to my class.

```
Clock clock1 = new(2, 10);
Clock clock2 = new(2, 10);
if (clock2.Equals(clock1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Equal");
}
```

Second scenario: changing my `class` to `record` type and comparing two objects with `==` operator

```
Clock clock1 = new(2, 10);
Clock clock2 = new(2, 10);
if (clock1 == clock2)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Equal");
}
```

In the both cases they return true. I wonder does `Equals` method does exact same thing as `==` ?

Comment: "This modification adds a bit more detail about what you did when changing the class to a record type and clarifies that you replaced the Equals method with the == operator." - what do you mean? (Was this something from ChatGPT or similar?)

Comment: I am sorry for that, just wanted to paraphrase my body using chatgpt and forgot to remove that part. @JonSkeet

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#value-equality suggests that yes, `==` and `!=` operators are generated for you - and while it's not *explicit* that those do the same as `Equals`, it would be odd for it generate anything different for the two. But you should be able to still use `Equals` anyway. It's not *entirely* clear to me exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try to modify the question to be more understandable why I'm asking. @JonSkeet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with a few basic assumptions, `==` for a record is the same as the `Equals` you wrote. From the [proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records) for records,

> The synthesized `Equals(R?)` returns true if and only if each of the
> following are true:
>
> - `other` is not null, and
> - For each instance field `fieldN` in the record type that is not inherited, the value of
>   `System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<TN>.Default.Equals(fieldN, other.fieldN)` where `TN` is the field type, and
> - If there is a base record type, the value of `base.Equals(other)` (a non-virtual call to `public virtual bool Equals(Base? other)`);
>   otherwise the value of `EqualityContract == other.EqualityContract`.

> The record type includes synthesized `==` and `!=` operators
> equivalent to operators declared as follows:
>
> ```
> public static bool operator==(R? left, R? right)
>     => (object)left == right || (left?.Equals(right) ?? false);
> public static bool operator!=(R? left, R? right)
>     => !(left == right);
> ```
>
> The `Equals` method called by the `==` operator is the `Equals(R? other)` method specified above.

Your `Clock.Equals` satisfy the conditions for the synthesised `Equals` to return true if we assume a few basic things, such as:

- `_hours` and `_minutes` are the only fields of `Clock`
- the types of `_hours` and `_minutes` are `int`s, or anything such that the default equality comparer for that type returns the same thing as comparing them with `==`.
- `Clock` doesn't have derived records (`EqualityContract` will always be equal)